# Keithley 2410 Pymeasure NotImplementedError: Please upgrade PyVISA to version 1.8 or later

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pyvisa

I am trying to interface with the Keithley 2410 Sourcemeter using an NI GPIB-USB cable, but I am getting the error above.

I have the NI-VISA installed as well as the NI-488.2 drivers. Windows and NI MAX are detecting the GPIB connection fine. I am running Jupyter Notebook in Windows 10 32-Bit.

```
 import pyvisa
 from pymeasure.instruments.keithley import Keithley2400

 rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
 print(rm.list_resources())

 sourcemeter = Keithley2400("GPIB::24")
 print(sourcemeter.id)
```

The list_resources() returns the following:
`('USB0::0x0957::0x2007::MY49019271::INSTR', 'ASRL1::INSTR', 
     'ASRL3::INSTR', 'ASRL4::INSTR')`

And I get the error: `NotImplementedError: Please upgrade PyVISA to version 1.8 or later.` Even though I am using version 1.10.

Any insight would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the computer I was using was garbage. We replaced it and this works with the new one.